# How to connect HANA SQL to Laravel using PDO

Tags: laravel, pdo, odbc, hana

I need to connect HANA SQL to the Laravel framework using PDO. It's working through ODBC but the eloquent ORM is not properly working when I use ODBC. So, please help me to connect using PDO.
I need to know what's the proper way to connect Laravel to HANA SQL.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Not working" is not really explaining the problem, why can't you connect using pdo? what is the config you've tried (hide password)? what is the error when connecting using pdo?

Comment: I don't how to connect using PDO that's the problem.